# How to create a relation in Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, relational-database, symfony-1.4

i learn Symfony and Doctrine with Jobeet. I would like add relation in JobeetJob.
this is original: 
http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/03

I do like this:

```
JobeetCategory:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }

JobeetCategorya:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    name: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }

JobeetJob:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
    category_id:  { type: integer, notnull: true }
    categorya_id:  { type: integer, notnull: true }
    type:         { type: string(255) }
    (...)
    expires_at:   { type: timestamp, notnull: true }
  relations:
    JobeetCategory: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: category_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: JobeetJobs }
    JobeetCategorya: { onDelete: CASCADE, local: categorya_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: JobeetJobsa }
```

when i do:

> php symfony doctrine:build --all
>   --and-load

i have error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jobeet`.`jobeet_job`, CONSTRAINT `jobeet_job_categorya_id_jobeet_categorya_id` FOREIGN KEY (`categorya_id`) REFERENCES `jobeet_categorya` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

why?

Comment: Patrick, you should formulate your title as a question and as Jobeet is symfony/doctrine, put that in there as well. This helps that others will spot a question they can probably answer. Just a suggestion: `How to create a relation in Doctrine?`

Comment: What do you do, when you get the error?

Comment: i do: php symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load

Comment: Add that into your question like: When I do `doctrine:build --all --and-load` then I get this error: (your error message is already in the question so put it in between)

Comment: ok :) may know the solution to the problem?

Comment: :) I'm not a doctrine specialist to give you an easy answer. What I see is that this is related to the foreign keys and those are somewhat blocking themselves. E.g. you want to insert data but the data can never be inserted because of the integrity checks / foreign key dependencies. But I think someone familiar with doctrine can much better explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking the problem is caused by the `--and-load` part of that command. That error comes up often when you're loading fixtures into tables in an order that would violate their foreign key relationships (i.e. putting child data in before parent data).

If this is indeed your problem, you can find several threads here on how to work around this issue... basically, by just building first (`build --all`), and then loading fixtures in separate batches so they respect the foreign key relationships.